# Como pegar o pid de um processo windows logo apos do processo ser executado

Tags: windows, batch, processo

Como pegar o pid de um processo do Windows logo após o processo ser executado, semelhante ao comando `$!` que recupera o pid do processo que foi executado.

Preciso de uma forma de pegar esse pid no comando do windows para aplicar à um script batch. Alguma sugestão de como proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer uma pesquisa no retorno dos utilitários `tasklist` e `wmic` com o comando `for`, em ambos é necessário passar o nome do processo.

Nos exemplos abaixo defini a variável app com o nome do aplicativo que eu quero saber o PID.

> Exemplo com tasklist:

```
set app=notepad.exe

start %app%

for /F "TOKENS=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %app%"') do set MyPID=%%b
echo %MyPID%

pause
```

> Exemplo com wmic:

```
set app=notepad.exe

start %app%

for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='%app%'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do set MyPID=%%a
echo  %MyPID%

pause
```

[Resposta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486960/how-to-get-pid-of-process-just-started-from-within-a-batch-file)

Comment: obrigado, estarei testando esse código durante semana.

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - Perceba que não temos um comando **disponível** / **especifico** para obter essa **informação** no **sistema** <kbd>[**Windows**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365079/como-pegar-o-pid-de-um-processo-windows-logo-apos-do-processo-ser-executado)</kbd>, a opção foi fazer um <kbd>**[bat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365079/como-pegar-o-pid-de-um-processo-windows-logo-apos-do-processo-ser-executado)**</kbd> para obter essa informação ...

Execute um **processo/programa** e  logo após rode esse bat para obter o **Process ID**

> <kbd>**[`* Observações necessárias:`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365079/como-pegar-o-pid-de-um-processo-windows-logo-apos-do-processo-ser-executado)**</kbd>

Para se obter o **PID** **(process ID)** via um **bat**, usaremos alguns **comandos** que serão **visíveis** na **execução** do **próprio bat**, e empregaremos alguns **filtros** nestes **comandos** utilizados, para obter o **último PID**, evitando que seja o **próprio comando utilizado** identificado como **último IPD**

Como poderá ver no código abaixo, os comandos utilizados estão sendo filtrados nas **listagens/execuções**, evitando, por exemplo, que <kbd>**[`TaskList`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365079/como-pegar-o-pid-de-um-processo-windows-logo-apos-do-processo-ser-executado)**</kbd> seja o **último** processo iniciado, e identificado **erroneamente** na execução pelo  próprio **bat** procurando o **último processo executado**...

> <kbd>**[`Get_Last_PID.cmd`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365079/como-pegar-o-pid-de-um-processo-windows-logo-apos-do-processo-ser-executado)**</kbd>

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title <nul
    
rem :: arquivos excluidos da busca/listagem de tarefas e serão usado nesse script ::  
set "_dt_criacao=wmic process get name^,creationdate"
set "_ignoras_01=findstr /vli "tasklist. findstr. cmd.""
set "_ignoras_02=findstr /vli "WMIC. WmiPrvSE.""
    
:: contagem de processos e setando para pular 90% (aproximadamente) no looping for
for /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%c in ('wmic process get name^,creationdate^|find /V /C "^^"')do set "_cnt=%%c"
set /a _skip=(!_cnt! * 90) / 100
    
for /f "skip=%_skip%tokens=1,2delims=%_tab%, " %%i in ('!_dt_criacao!^|!_ignoras_01!^|!_ignoras_02!')do (
    if /i "./" equ "./%%j" goto :_continue_: 
    set "_time_id=%%i" & set "_time_=!_time_id:~8,-4!" & set "_name=%%j"
    set "_time_=!_time_:~,13!" & set "_time_=!_time_:~0,2!:!_time_:~2,2!:!_time_:~4,5!"
    for /f "tokens=1,2delims= " %%P in ('tasklist^|findstr /i "!_name!"')do set "_name_=%%P" & set "_pid=%%Q"
    ) 2>nul 
:_continue_:
echo/ Ultimo Processo Iniciado !_name_! hora !_time_! PID !_pid!
```